# How to load an array in UIWebView in Xcode 4.6 by using HTMLString?

Tags: arrays, uiwebview, nsstring

hello friends i am new to iPhone please do help me.And my question is how to load this array in UIWebView?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];

  first_heading = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Vocabulary", @"Grammar",
                                 @"Right or wrong?",@"Grammar",
                                 @"Right or wrong?",@"Vocabulary",
                                 @"Right or wrong?",@"Grammar",
                                 @"Right or wrong?",@"Grammar",
                                 @"Vocabulary",@"Grammar",@"Grammar",@"Vocabulary",
                                 @"Grammar",@"Vocabulary",@"Vocabulary",
                                 @"Grammar",@"Right or wrong?",@"Grammar",
                                 @"Grammar",@"Right or wrong?",@"Vocabulary",
                                 @"Grammar",@"Right or wrong?",@"Grammar",nil];

 NSString *htmlstring =[first_heading objectAtIndex:0];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlstring baseURL:nil];
```

}

Comment: Start by making sure that `htmlstring` is a string that contains actual HTML.

Comment: What you exactly mean with : "load an array into the webview"?